# Select a range of rows from a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am very new to PHP and MySQL. I am trying to write a php script and i am stucking with the selection of rows from a table

The code that works great is:

```
$q_pages = $wpdb -> prefix . 'q_pages_table';

$q_kws = $wpdb->prefix . 'q_kws_table';

$sql = 'SELECT a1.post_id, a1.kw_id, a2.kw_name ' +
       'FROM ' . $q_pages . ' as a1 ' +
       'LEFT JOIN ' . $q_kws . ' as a2 ON (a1.kw_id = a2.id)' + 
       'WHERE a1.draft_id = 4';
```

The third command is to select and join columns from variable $q_kws to variable $q_pages if there is a match between kw_id and id in the 2 tables and also when the draft_id = 4

Because of the large number of rows in the $sql variable (3000 rows), i want to break $sql to 3 variables, each variable contains 1000 rows, so that later i can process each variable separately.

Is there any suggestion?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can use limit in the query to retrieve a specific number of rows .

something like 
$start=0;
$end=1000;

$sql = 'SELECT a1.post_id, a1.kw_id, a2.kw_name ' +
       'FROM ' . $q_pages . ' as a1 ' +
       'LEFT JOIN ' . $q_kws . ' as a2 ON (a1.kw_id = a2.id)' + 
       'WHERE a1.draft_id = 4 limit ".$start.",".$end."';
```

Answer (score 1):

To select a specific range, you have to use `limit [start number], [# to select]` so in your case, you'd select the first 1000 rows like:

```
select [your select stuff]
limit 0, 1000
```

The second one would be:

```
select [your select stuff]
limit 1000, 1000
```

and the third would be

```
select [your select stuff]
limit 2000, 1000
```

The first number in the limit is the row that it starts at, and the second number is the number of rows after and including that row that will be selected

Comment: Hi Jake,Thank you very much for your response so quickly. I'm still not sure how to modify my code.

Comment: Your SQL statement is fine, you just need to have three variables that are all the same as the the `$sql` variable you have now, but append the `limit` stuff I mentioned to the end of each one.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
select * from table where rownum < 1000
```